# "the linq expression [...] could not be translated"

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to use LINQ methods to filte a list of client by cheking whether or not the client is in a table of my BDD

```
using(var db = new dbContext())
            {
                var activeAccount = db.AccountBase.Where(account => account.StateCode == 0);
                
                List<Client> toImport = clients.Where(client => activeAccount
                .Where(account => account.IsAccountSageNumberForAgency(client.CODECLIENT, new Guid("2CA81DBC-8261-EB11-B061-00155D53D276")))
                .Any()).ToList();
            }
```

LINQ cannot translate that expression. I've checked the type of my elements to make sure that none of the ones inside the queries are IEnumerable. Can't find the origin of the problem.

This expression works :
`var test = activeAccount.Where(account => account.IsAccountSageNumberForAgency("", new Guid("2CA81DBC-8261-EB11-B061-00155D53D276")));`

is it because I get client.CODECLIENT in a Where() that is inside an other Where() and client is the in the first predicate?

Comment: it's because you are using method `Account.IsAccountSageNumberForAgency` which cannot be translated to SQL ... there are already asked similar questions - you may find them to find the solution

Comment: Your `activeAccount.Where(...)` works because it executes in-memory, where that `IsAccountSageNumberForAgency` method is available. `db.AccountBase.Where(...)` should be translated into SQL but fails because that method does not exist there

Comment: Show the code of IsAccountSageNumberForAgency

Answer (score -1):

"Linq" is confusing here. On one side you have the "traditional" Linq, that works on `IEnumerable` and does all the processing in memory. On the other side you have Frameworks like Entity Framework that uses a Linq-like interface to compose queries. Ef Core is actually based on "Linq2Sql". EF converts your Linq to SQL and sends that to the server (it works on the `IQueryable` type. But not everything can be converted to SQL. In your case you're calling a specific method of a class, which is specific to your C# code. The SQL server doesn't know anything about it. And EF cannot convert it an expression.

Unless you can make something that *can* run on the server, you will need to pull the data to the local memory. You can do that with `AsEnumerable`.

E.g.

```cs
List<Client> toImport = clients
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(client => activeAccount
        .Where(account => account
            .IsAccountSageNumberForAgency(
                client.CODECLIENT,
                new Guid("2CA81DBC-8261-EB11-B061-00155D53D276")))
        .Any())
    .ToList();
```

Note, this will pull all data from the server to the local memory, thus costs memory and performance

Answer (score -1):

Your query cannot be executed on the database side, so you will have to do it client side, by loading all the objects in memory.
You can use `ToList()` to achieve this.
By example :

```cs
using(var db = new CrmXefi())
{
    var activeAccount = db.AccountBase.Where(account => account.StateCode == 0);
    List<Client> toImport = clients.ToList().Where(client => activeAccount
    .Where(account => account.IsAccountSageNumberForAgency(client.CODECLIENT, new Guid("2CA81DBC-8261-EB11-B061-00155D53D276")))
    .Any()).ToList();
}
```